# Swift 2 / Xcode 7.0 - initializer for conditional binding must have optional type not 'nsmanagedobjectcontext'

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

Just updated to Xcode 7.0 from Xcode 6.4. In my project I am getting an error now which I try to solve the whole night and did not get it.

The error message is: **Initializer for conditional binding must have optional type not 'nsmanagedobjectcontext'**

The error is coming twice in lines **if let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext {** in following code

```
func preloadData () {
    // Retrieve data from the source file
    if let contentsOfURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("listofdata", withExtension: "csv") {

        // Remove all the items before preloading
        removeData()

        var error:NSError?
        if let items = parseCSV(contentsOfURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) {
            // Preload the items
            if let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext {
                for item in items {
                    let listOfItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ListOfItem", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! ListOfItem
                    listOfItem.name = item.name
                    listOfItem.address = item.address
                    listOfItem.phone = item.phone

                    if managedObjectContext.save(&error) != true {
                        print("insert error: \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func removeData () {
    // Remove the existing items
    if let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext {
        let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ListOfItem")
        var e: NSError?
        let listOfItems = managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: &e) as! [ListOfItem]

        if e != nil {
            print("Failed to retrieve record: \(e!.localizedDescription)")

        } else {

            for listOfItem in listOfItems {
                managedObjectContext.deleteObject(listOfItem)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate all help! Thanks!

**Update:**

The updated code looks like this, but still have these two errors in the first function **preloadData**:

1. Missing argument for parameter 'error' in call
2. Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'NSManagedObjectContext'

   ```
   func preloadData () {
   // Retrieve data from the source file
   if let contentsOfURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("listofdata", withExtension: "csv") {

       // Remove all the menu items before preloading
       removeData()

       do {
           let items = try parseCSV(contentsOfURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
           // Preload the items
           if let managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext {
               for item in items {
                   let listOfItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("ListOfItem", inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! ListOfItem
                   listOfItem.name = item.name
                   listOfItem.address = item.address
                   listOfItem.phone = item.phone

                   if managedObjectContext.save() != true {
                       print("insert error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                   }
               }
           }
       } catch let error as NSError {
           print("insert error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
       }
   }
   ```

This function shows no errors

```
func removeData () {
    // Remove the existing items
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ListOfItem")

    do {
        let listOfItems = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [ListOfItem]
        for listOfItem in listOfItems {
            self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(listOfItem)
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to retrieve record: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
```

Can some help? Thanks!

Comment: How have you declared `self.managedObjectContext`

Comment: @Olli D. Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 2 the `Core Data` template implements the property `managedObjectContext`  in `AppDelegate` as non-optional. Probably the updater changed the implementation accordingly.

The benefit is that the optional bindings are not necessary any more, but you have to consider the new error handling for example

```
func removeData () {
  let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "ListOfItem")

  do {
    let listOfItems = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [ListOfItem]
    for listOfItem in listOfItems {
       self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(listOfItem)
     }
   }
   catch let error as NSError {
     print("Failed to retrieve record: \(error.localizedDescription)")
   }
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence is misleading, `NSManagedObjectContext` does not have a `managedObjectContext` variable. Perhaps you meant the `managedObjectContext` property of the application delegate? – Then, strictly speaking, this is not a change in the Swift language, but a change in the template code generated by Xcode 7.

Comment: vielen dank vadian! it looks like that the second function (func removeData) is working as you described it. I just had to add a "try" in the "do" statement: let listOfDgItem = try NSEntityDescription.insertNew....I want to correct the first function (fun preloadData) in same way but its not working. Now I am a light bit confused. Any idea how it could look?

Answer (score 1):

try below code

**removeData()**

```
 func removeData () {

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MenuItem")

    do {
        let listOfItems = try self.managedObjectContext.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest) as! [MenuItem]
        for listOfItem in listOfItems {
            self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(listOfItem)
        }
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print("Failed to retrieve record: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }


}
```

**preloadData ()**

```
 func preloadData () {
    // Retrieve data from the source file
    if let contentsOfURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("menudata", withExtension: "csv") {

        // Remove all the menu items before preloading
        removeData()

        var error:NSError?
        if let items = parseCSV(contentsOfURL, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) {
            // Preload the menu items

                for item in items {

                    let menuItem =  NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("MenuItem", inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext) as! MenuItem
                    menuItem.name = item.name
                    menuItem.detail = item.detail
                    menuItem.price = (item.price as NSString).doubleValue

            }

        }
    }
}
```